Invisible entity that is affected by motion but not gravity [1.21.3]
I'm trying to find an entity that is 100% invisible, affected by motion, not affected by gravity, and does not despawn on its own.
I've already tried the following entities with the following NBT and drawbacks:

Armor stands with Invisible and NoGravity (does not move at all with NoGravity tag)
Falling blocks with barrier blockstate, no DropItem, CancelDrop, and NoGravity (Despawns when it hits the ground)
Various mobs with an invisibility potion effect, Silent, Invulnerable, and NoGravity (still shows up for a single frame when summoned)

For context, I'm making a datapack where a sword is swung, and this entity would be a continuously moving hitbox for hit detection. Because I want it to be standalone, I'm also trying to avoid using a resource pack to make the entity invisible.
If there are any other ideas for creating this functionality, that would be great.

You could summon an entity elsewhere, give it invisibility and then teleport it to the target location one tick later.

What do you need the hitbox to do? Can you tp it in front of the player constantly or would that not work? What 'motion' are you talking about, and how is it implemented on the target?

@FabianRöling You should consider posting that as an answer.

Then I would prefer to do some experimentation first. My comment is a pretty janky situation, not really ideal in any way.
